# Passing values back to be rendered by Jade, using Express and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I asked a question yesterday, but I've kept going with it.  Instead of calling next() and passing an an Error object, I worked out what it was doing, and tried to copy it.  Now, when someone logs in and it fails, I do this:

```
   res.render("pages/home", 
            {
                flash:{"danger":["Login failed. Please enter your details and try again."]},
                body:{},
                section:"home",
                locals : { userId : req.body.email } 
            }
```

This does exactly the same thing as the old code.  I step through it, and I can see that the locals object contains a property called userId, with the value I expect.  In the Jade template, I have this:

```
    p it's #{typeof(userId)}
    if(typeof(userId) != 'undefined')
        p Welcome #{userId}
        input(type='text', name='email', id="inputEmail", placeholder="Email", value="#{userId}")
    else
        input(type='text', name='email', id="inputEmail", placeholder="Email", value="")
```

This always renders as 'it's undefined' and then an empty text box.  I have read several questions on this, and as far as I can see, they all say the same thing: if I set locals to be a JSON object, I can access it's properties by this syntax, but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try `#{locals.userId}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might first need to better understand how `locals` object actually work.

On the server-side, doing this:

```
res.render('view', { property: 'value' } );
```

would make `property` available in your views like so:

```
div Value = #{property}
```

You can also do the following to have the same effect:

```
res.locals.property = 'value';
res.render('views');
```

Note the usage of `locals` object. [More info](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals)

---

Coming back to your issue, since you have

```
res.render("pages/home", { locals: { userId : req.body.email } })
```

to access `userId` in this case you would do:

```
p Welcome #{locals.userId}
```

So I'm guess you're confusing the two approaches ending up using `locals` object the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you.  I think that is exactly where I went wrong. I was googling for help and I think the nature of 'locals' has changed along the way ( found a post that said that, anyhow )

Answer (score 1):

OK - turns out that 'locals' doesn't mean anything any more.  Leaving my code as it is, I needed to access 'locals.userId', but I could have just set the value of 'userId' and not had the 'locals' object at all.

Comment: That is true, your object is now locals, but not using locals as you think.